# pdb file is being removed by "Target IncrementalClean"

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, mono

I have an issue with a project that I am working on right now. The issue is that Visual Studio will not stop in any breakpoint. Then I look at the bin folder and I don't see the .pdb file at all.

This explain why the my breakpoints are not being hit. Then I start to investigate and I found out that whenever I compile this project in MacOS using Visual Studio of Mac. I am getting this entry in the build output.

```
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
   Copying file from "obj/Debug/HelloWorld.dll" to "bin/Debug/HelloWorld.dll".
   HelloWorld -> /Users/frank_underwood/Documents/Github/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/HelloWorld.dll
   Copying file from "obj/Debug/HelloWorld.pdb" to "bin/Debug/HelloWorld.pdb".
Target IncrementalClean:
   Deleting file "/Users/frank_underwood/Documents/Github/HelloWorld/bin/Debug//HelloWorld.pdb".
```

Yes the "//" in the last line is not a mistype by me, but that is how the entry was generated.

Here is my environment:

- Mac OSX 10.12.5
- Visual Studio for Mac 2017 (Community Edition)
- .Net Framework 4.5.2
- Debug Mode

Here is the csproj file looks like:
https://gist.github.com/danielmahadi/9e13ac73ef41be6d0e6bdddc4f19d985

Has this ever happen to anyone here? How to resolve this? any further investigation that I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you create the project via VS or did you use an existing one? Can you share the csproj file? (I can't reproduce it with a newly created project)

Comment: H Martini, Thanks for you response. I added the csprog to GitHub gist.. https://gist.github.com/danielmahadi/9e13ac73ef41be6d0e6bdddc4f19d985

Comment: Are you using the latest version of VS/Mac with all updates? I still can't reproduce it with your csproj, but I see that the default templates don't have a trailing backslash in the `<OutputPath>` properties (which msbuild would normalise to `/` on Mac). you can try removing those and see if it fixes your build.

Comment: It doesn't help. I tried to run as "Release" and the pdb file is there and the "IncrementalClean" is not in the build output entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has this ever happen to anyone here? How to resolve this? any further investigation that I can do?

I could not reproduce this issue with your csproj too, I have no direct solution for this issue, but I could provide you a workaround to resolve this issue temporarily.

You can add a new target to copy necessary files to the target folder. 
For example(edit csproj file, add this code to the end (before ):

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Copy
       SourceFiles="obj\Debug\HelloWorld.pdb"
       DestinationFolder="bin\Debug"
    />
```

**Update**:

I have found a [similar issue on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1054), if possible, you can get some more useful information about this issue.

Hope this can help you.